# Robospice. Retry failed request on demand

Tags: android, request, robospice

I need to implement quite popular template of app behaviour - give opportunity to user to retry failed requests. Right now I catch failed request with `SpiceServiceListener`, and shows dialog where user can press "Retry" button. Unfortunately, using the same CachedSpiceRequest object with `SpiceManager.execute()` don't give desired behaviour, because RS removing all request listeners from `mapRequestToLaunchToRequestListener` if request wasn't successful. So request can work fine, but it will not return any information to my Activity.

Is there easy way (without modifying code of library) to implement this?

Comment: Looks like removing of the listeners isn't the only problem. `SpiceRequest` has many "state variables" (`isCanceled`,`future`, `progress`), so reusing it without proper reinitialization of such variables can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Please share if you've found the solution, I need retrying in case of OAuth token expiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately looks like there are no abstract solution for situation like this, so I had to add code like this in every request.

```
    getSpiceManager().execute(r, new RequestListener<CountProfiles>() {
        @Override
        public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException spiceException) {
            if (act.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("network_problem") == null) {
                NetworkProblemDialogFragm.newInstance(r, this).show(act.getSupportFragmentManager(), "network_problem");
            } else {
                ((NetworkProblemDialogFragm) act.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("network_problem")).setSpiceRequest(r);
                ((NetworkProblemDialogFragm) act.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("network_problem")).setRequestListener(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestSuccess(CountProfiles countProfiles) {
        }
    });
```

NetworkProblemDialogFragm is a DialogFragment with **Retry** button, on click on this button I re execute failed request, using given RequestListener.

Not very beautiful solution, but looks like there no better one.